# How do i do setOnClickListener in Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-view

Please i'm noob in android,i just have been assigned a task and i need to finish it in two days,

I need to set Onclicklistener(this),i received a code from someone,and i had to make changes to it,i'm trying to implement this in Fragment

```
  View sortableHeaderWrappers[]=new View[]{view.findViewById(R.id.date_wrapper),view.findViewById(R.id.status_wrapper)};
```

And then there's something written as

```
for(int i=0;i<sortableHeaderWrappers.length;i++)
    {
        sortableHeaderWrappers[i].setTag((Integer)i);
        sortableHeaderWrappers[i].setOnClickListener(this)
    }
```

But i'm not able to use this,i understand you can use getContext() instead of "this",but thats not working as well

Any inputs would be helpful

Comment: what problem you are facing? any error log?

Comment: first implement on click listener in your fragment then your this will work.

Comment: have you tried sortableHeaderWrappers[i].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { @override public void click(View v) { //do your stuff }});

Comment: make ur fragment implement View.OnClickListener

Comment: @MohammedAtif yea its there,i've used Fragment implements View.Onclicklistener

Comment: @AbdulWaheed sortableHeaderWrappers[i].setOnClickListener(this) works on Activity,how can i use it in fragment

Comment: @Roy,i have used View.Onclicklistener

Comment: please post whole fragment code. I doubt you have nested inner class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can initialize a new onClickListener in for loop.

```
for(int i=0;i<sortableHeaderWrappers.length;i++)
    {
        sortableHeaderWrappers[i].setTag((Integer)i);
        sortableHeaderWrappers[i].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
 @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
                //.. place your logic that needs to be executed when click happens. 
   }
})
    }
```