# How i can make a bidge layout1.xml to layout2.xml when its Fragment1.java to Fragment2.java on Android Studio

Tags: android

to me dont show any error but dont execute anything, to make bridge of `fragment1.java` to `fragment2.java`

Why?

```
public class ProfileFragment extends Fragment {

private Button btnTEST;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.profile,container,false);
    btnTEST = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnseguinte);

    btnTEST.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "apears toast",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://www.hiihihih.com"));
            //Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), ProfileFragmentCapilar2.class);
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            intent.putExtras(bundle);
        }
    });

    return view;
}
}
```

Comment: Unclear what your trying to do

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters

Answer (score 0):

By your question it seems that you want to send data from From Fragment1 to Fragment2. For this purpose you have to use Interface for communicating the two fragments. See the below link: http://vinsol.com/blog/2014/09/25/inter-fragment-communication/

Comment: Can you help me on this?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43971930/how-do-i-do-setonclicklistener-in-fragment

Comment: Wrong link :P its this 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55305079/how-i-can-put-a-intent-toast-setonclicklistener-on-fragment-at-each-list-item